# Why is 'when' used with a past simple instead of a past perfect?

Tags: past-perfect, past-simple

I've come across the following:

**(A)**

> Joe had been on a diet for a month when he came to stay with us, and we noticed immediately that he had already lost a lot of weight.

According to [Advanced Grammar in Use: A Self-study Reference and Practice Book for Advanced Learners of English; with Answers](https://books.google.com.mx/books/about/Advanced_Grammar_in_Use_with_Answers.html?id=aLj2wyTtAQkC&printsec=frontcover&source=kp_read_button&redir_esc=y),

> With times clauses introduced by **after**, **when** ... the past simple refers to the past, completed events and the present perfect to future events ...
>
> □ *After* she **left** the hospital (past), she had a long holiday.
>
> ... In the time clause in sentences like this it is possible to use the past perfect instead of the past simple (e.g. After she **had left**...) ...

(p. 6)

Why in **(A)** the author chose to use the past simple instead of the past perfect? Is it a matter of style? Is it because of the way it's phrased? From my experience, it would sound unnatural to use past perfect.

Comment: Joe had been on a diet for a month when he came to stay with us = because at the point in time when he came, an event preceded it: He had been on diet for a month. This follows the basic rule for PP.

Comment: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/156540/which-perfect-tense-to-use-in-a-defining-clause-with-simple-past/156542#156542

Comment: @Lambie What about the rest ? "... and we noticed that ... " If  we follow that rule, won't it make "when he had come"  instead of "when he came"?

Comment: No, when he came (at a specific time in the past), he had been (BEFORE that past point in time and up to it) on a diet. Please write this down and memorize it: The past perfect **always implies a previous event in the simple past or sometimes continuous that *precedes it*.** When he **had come** to the house, we **were out**. It is always the same thing: One event in the past **precedes another**.

Comment: @Lambie If 'he came' happened before 'we noticed', then why not 'he had come'?